# Which RFID and RFID Reader to use?

Tags: iot

I want to make use of RFIDs which will continuously transmit some information and the reader will read it. I want range of RFID reader atleast 10 meter. Which RFID reader can provide this?

Comment: There are many frequencies to use depending of whatever you want to accomplished, but now days, UHF RAIN RFID (ISO-1800-6C) is the one more commonly use, more standarized, many vendors to choose from; and pricing is going down. You can achieve 10 m easily, but is a combination of the RFID tag, antenna, reader and environment you are reading the tags, where do you apply the tags to, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATA5590 chip operates in the 800-MHz to 1-GHz range and can achieve a range up to about 10 meters depending upon the interrogation device. Also called TAGIDU, the device contains 1344 bits of EEPROM, 1024 bits of user memory for the electronic product code, and 320 bits of system memory.

The forward interrogator to the tag can use either amplitude-shift keying (ASK) or double-sideband (DSB) modulation. The tag to interrogator modulation may be ASK or phase-shift keying (PSK), depending on the desired operation range, bit rate, and security mechanism. The data-rate range is 5 to 80 kbits/s.

The device can achieve a 10-meter range with an interrogator equivalent isotropic radiated power (EIRP) of 4 W. Range is less than 4 meters with an EIRP of 500 mW. An anticollision function enables the operation of multiple tags within the field range for the reader. It can distinguish between up to 460 tags per second. Total tag power consumption is only 10 µW.

[Source: UHF RFID Chip Extends Reading Range To 10 Meters](http://electronicdesign.com/communications/uhf-rfid-chip-extends-reading-range-10-meters)